# Conditional CASE WHEN select snowflake SQL

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I am stuck on a conditional snowflake select sql. I am trying to count the IDs when they have the corresponding categorial value. I would appreciate some help.

Thanks

```
SELECT 
YEAR(DATETIME) AS YEAR, 
WEEKOVERYEAR(DATETIME) AS WEEK,
COUNT(CASE WHEN ID THEN CATEGORY = 'A')
from table 
group by week, year;
```

Comment: Are ID values duplicated in your data? The results of a `DESCRIBE TABLE` or `GET_DDL` statement may be helpful as well. From the bit that's in the question, Gordon's answer should work. If it doesn't, we'll need more detail to understand why.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is one method:

```
SELECT YEAR(DATETIME) AS YEAR, 
       WEEKOVERYEAR(DATETIME) AS WEEK,
       SUM(CASE WHEN CATEGORY = 'A' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as num_a
FROM table 
GROUP BY week, year;
```

Comment: Hi Gordon, thanks for the answer but I am trying to count on the condition that IDs and CATEGORY = 'A'

Comment: @B.Choi That's what Gordon's query does. Summing based on the 1 and 0 of the condition will give you the correct result. If you are trying to do a count distinct of results you can do this: COUNT(DISTINCT CASE WHEN CATEGORY = 'A' THEN id END)

Comment: If I have tried both options from Brock and Gordon and I am getting Boolean value '...' is not recognised....

Comment: is the "category" field a boolean? can you post your exact SQL you are using and the exact error message?

Answer (score 2):

You should / can use IFF() since case when is more suitable when there are multiple conditions.

```
SELECT 
    YEAR(DATETIME) AS YEAR, 
    WEEKOVERYEAR(DATETIME) AS WEEK,
    COUNT(IFF(CATEGORY = 'A',ID,NULL)) as count
    from table 
    group by week, year;
```

Answer (score 1):

Snowflake supports [COUNT_IF](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/count_if.html):

> Returns the number of records that satisfy a condition.
>
> Aggregate function
>
> ```
> COUNT_IF( <condition> )
> ```

```
SELECT YEAR(DATETIME) AS YEAR, 
       WEEKOVERYEAR(DATETIME) AS WEEK,
       COUNT_IF(CATEGORY = 'A') AS num_a
FROM tab
GROUP BY week, year;
```

Answer (score 0):

COUNT() counts the number of rows that are not null.
If you are want when ID is not null AND CATEGORY = 'A' then

```
COUNT(CASE WHEN ID IS NOT NULL AND CATEGORY = 'A' THEN TRUE ELSE NULL END)
```

will give you that, or you can use a SUM like in Gordon's answer

```
SUM(CASE WHEN ID IS NOT NULL AND CATEGORY = 'A' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)
```

or you can use the snowflake IFF as a shorter form for the same thing, which is how I do it

```
SUM( IFF( ID IS NOT NULL AND CATEGORY = 'A', 1, 0))
```

Comment: `IFF()` can be nicer to look at, just remember it is non-standard.
Used eg. by Microsoft T-SQL, but not by Oracle.

Comment: Oh forsure, it's not hard to REGEX for, if portability becomes your thing, I just prefer to write for the tool at hand, not some future not going to happen state.. which also means you can make it not happen in the future by making the cost to port too high (maybe a feature of the Oracle front), but also we write a lot of SQL where results are input on the next line which is also non-standard... mostly we focus of readability of our SQL code..

Comment: You'r right, readability usually betters portability for a Data Warehouse, and chances are slim you will port your Snowflake DB back to Oracle (at least if the tech dept has any say).